# How to merge a column from a dataframe to another based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following CSV files:

```
file1.csv #dataframe is named dfFile1
Id,name,pos_neg,line
1,abc,pos,cas
2,cde,neg,work
3,efg,pos,cat
4,abc,pos,job

file2.csv #dataframe is named dfFile2
Id,ref,names,other
c10,n1,www,10.5
c11,m4,efg,5.4
c12,m5,cde,9.8
c13,m9,hhh,6.7
c14,n4,abc,12.5
c15,n9,kkk,3.4
```

which I converted into dataframes using pandas. I would like to obtain a third data frame that matches the rows of dfFile2 according to the unique values presented in the **name** field of dfFile1, and also add the **pos_neg** row from file 1, so I will end up with:

```
dfNew
Id,ref,names,other,pos_neg
c11,m4,efg,5.4,pos
c12,m5,cde,9.8,neg
c14,n4,abc,12.5,pos
```

So far, I have done the following:

```
list=[]
list=dfFile1["name"].unique()    #contains [abc,cde,efg]
dfFile2=dfFile2[dfFile2.names.isin(list)]
```

However, I just do not know how can I merge the column **pos_neg** from dfFile1, I tried the following:

```
dfNew=dfFile2.merge(dfFile2,dfFil1[["pos_neg"]],on=dfFile2)
```

Unfortunately, it does not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output.

Comment: IMO this is a MCVE @AMC

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there, just some tweaking with the `DataFrame.merge` method, furthermore you need `drop_duplicates` here, since `abc` appears twice in the `dfFile1`.

```
dfNew = (
    dfFile2.merge(dfFile1[['name', 'pos_neg']], 
                  left_on='names', 
                  right_on='name')
    .drop_duplicates()
    .drop(columns='name')
)

    Id ref names  other pos_neg
0  c11  m4   efg    5.4     pos
1  c12  m5   cde    9.8     neg
2  c14  n4   abc   12.5     pos
```

Sidenote: in Python we don't use `camelCase` for variable names but lowercase with underscore `camel_case`. See [`PEP8 style guide`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.

Comment: the problem is that I need to validate that the names that appear on File1 also appear on File2, for that reason I need the unique() instruction

Comment: Can you edit your expected output, else add more details to your input, because right now my output matches yours.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I found that in my original dataset file 1 can have duplicates like 1,abc,pos,cas and also 10,abc,neg,cow; and for that reason the merge was giving me a strange result based on your answer. This was happening because for a same name it could have two different values of pos and neg based on other factors.I will try to fix that case of file 1 first.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through your dataframe with iterrows

```
df3 = df2[df2.names.isin(names)]

for index, row in df3.iterrows():
    row = df[row['names'] == df['name']]['pos_neg']
    df3.loc[index,'pos_neg'] = row.iloc[0]
```

row.loc[0] stands for rows that has same 'name' field. Gets first of same named rows

Comment: Thanks for welcoming :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dfNew = dfFile2.merge(dfFile1[["name", "pos_neg"]], how="inner", left_on="names", right_on="name")
```

Rearranging the columns and/or renaming them shouldn't be difficult if above works.

Comment: Thanks @NullDev, but I need to preserve the unique condition because on File1 there are repeated values on the name field